# Connect navigation bar button to view controller in xcode?

Tags: xcode, ios5, uiviewcontroller

I have made tabbed bar application.Then I put a navigation bar + bar button on one tab view.Then I put a separate view controller on my storyboard.Now i want to open that separate view on click of that bar button.I have tried this by connecting button to view controller with push option.But it does not works.please help?

Answer (score 0):

> Then I put a navigation bar + bar button on one tab view.

Seems that you have tried to add UINavigationBar by yourself and as a result (I guess) you have no UINavigationController on tab view. In this case your push segue will not work.
Just place UINavigationController on first tab. Place your bar button on navigationBar that owned by navigationController. The image will help you understand what I've said.
[image]